# How to insert audio/mp3 in Cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, html5-audio

```
<?php echo $this->Html->media('musica.mp3'); ?>
```

I'm trying this in the view.ctp  (USING CAKEPHP 2.5....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="musica.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="musica.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Yes, it supports. And plays by this way. But what about "$this->Html->media"? Does it work?

Comment: yes its the same thing : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::media